Can you sustain yourself with the water from Elementalism?
There is a new Transmutation cantrip in 5e called elementalism. One of its options is

Beckon Water. [...] Alternatively, you create 1 cup of clean water either in an open container or on a surface, and the water evaporates in 1 minute.

The question stems from the wording that says the water "evaporates", not that it "vanishes".
I know that D&D is not a physics simulation, so I'll ignore all the heat issues caused by the water "evaporating" (to evaporate in a very short time, much shorter than even boiling water, would mean very hot steam), and just assume the water magically evaporates while still being at ambient temperature.
What happens if you put a lid on the container after you created the water, and clamp it down, so that it can only evaporate within the container? It cannot escape and either blows up the container creating a shrapnel bomb, or will condense again within. I think the intention of a cantrip that says nothing about causing damage is to create harmless effects, so my conclusion here would be that it condenses harmlessly again if confined.
But that leads to the second, and main part of my question: if the evaporating water condenses harmlessly when confined, what happens if you drink it before the minute is up? Do you harmlessly retain the water in your body?
The motivation for the question comes from the fact that if you do, this spell will allow you at first level to create as much drinking water as you like, and remove any challenge of carrying water in a desert adventure.
It also makes the create food an water spell, which is a 3rd level spell, half unnecessary, because you now can create the water with a cantrip. Sure, create food and water creates 30 gallons of fresh water, enough to sustain a typical party with its mounts for a day. But that is just 480 cups. It would take you less than an hour of time to create them with elementalism, nevermind you can create them while you travel along. (There also is the goodberry spell that can sustain 10 creatures for 1 day with a single casting, at level one, together they will be removing any nourishment resource issues right from level 1).

“I know D&D is not a physics simulator, but what if it was?” is basically what you’re asking here.

@ThomasMarkov Thanks for the feedback, but it isn’t. My question is if you don’t it will imply that the spell can create arbitrary amounts of water, and is that how it is working, considering that it invalidates classical challenges and much higher level spells. The answer may be it is, but I’m not sure, hence the question. I edited the title to clarify.

Let's not pretend that survival challenges have really been challenging for a long time. They were completely invalidated by a background in 2014, and wotc have no idea how their exploration pillar works, or should work.

Very related, albeit for 2014-5e, Can the Prestidigitation cantrip create an "infinite" supply of food and water by repeatedly creating these trinkets?

Water "evaporating" off of my counter after a spill doesn't require it to boil. Pretty sure this is just a colloquial "evaporate" as in "the water is no longer there." Regardless of the actual scientific use of evaporate. Read as an English speaker, anyway.

Consider also this: create water was a 0-level spell in D&D 3.5. The fact that elementalism is measured as a cup might suggest that drinking is an intended purpose, and the main reason it needs to evaporate is to stop you flooding a room with infinite water (since 5e cantrips are unlimited-use).

@DarthPseudonym Indeed, the title of beckon water might suggest what you are actually doing is condensing it out of the air, and at the end of the duration it returns back into the air. In a humid environment, you might be able to continually take water out of the air as you drank it, but in a dry environment perhaps you use up the available water quickly

@DarthPseudonym And it is a transmutation spell, not conjuration.

Ask your DM, but I think a ruling that it can provide drinking water is well supported.
At the most fundamental level, I agree with Thomas Markov's answer. The text is ambiguous in a way that cannot be fully resolved other than by asking your specific DM unless an errata or direct designer statement is released.
With that said, I disagree about the most likely resolution. While there is definitely ambiguity, I think the text supports the idea that the water is potable.
The text itself states the water is clean. While that definitely matters for things other than drinking, it is most important in the context of drinking. In some contexts were it matters, organizations will set different standards for drinking and bathing water for instance in the real world.
The fact it can be summoned into an open container, such as a cup, also suggests to me that it is meant for drinking. Again, that is not the only possibility, and ambiguity remains, but that highly suggests in my mind that drinking is meant to be possibility.
I also don't think there should be much weight given to the idea that it can replicate a higher level spell. Because it doesn't. All of the similar higher level spells do more. Create Food and Water is the most obvious one, but that creates both food and water in large quantities quickly. This could at best replace half of that, arguably the lesser half, and do so only slowly.
Obviously if it did fully replicate a higher level spell, that would be an argument for a different reading of it, but kind-of-sort-of replicating half of a higher level spell is not problematic.
The most problematic part of course is that the water "evaporates" quickly. But I do not believe that would apply when drunk and integrated into a creature. That simply prevents you from storing up the water, just as Create Food and Water has language that prevents at least the created food from being stored long term. Water that is drunk does not evaporate so while the language certainly could be clearer, my reading is that applies to the water under normal conditions but would not apply when it was drunk or otherwise integrated into something else.
Fundamentally, the only final answer possible right now is to ask your DM, but I think the limited information available strongly supports a reading that the water can be drunk.

For the sake of providing some contrast: an argument against this would be that the water "evaporating" already breaks all known physics. Thus, whatever happens is not happening on charted territory. In other words, magic is magic. However, there is also a middle ground as a DM might decide to allow the water to be drunk but forbid excessive usage. Like, trying to water the entire desert or a party of adventurers (and maybe mounts) subsisting on solely this spell for water. Or even something further like drinking the water quenches your thirst but doesn't nourish you.

@VLAZ All goods points, and perhaps worthy of posting your own answer. It is ambiguous and arguments the other way certainly exist. I stand by my analysis that "yes, it can take care of drinking water needs" is the best reading, but this is absolutely an area where reasonable minds can disagree.

Thank you - this is the kind of "Ask your DM" answer I was looking for.

Also, another use of clean water is to clean your wounds.

Instantaneous change of state
Spells do what they say they do - and this beckons water
The description of the spell says that it can:

create 1 cup of clean water either in an open container or on a surface,...

Spells do what they say they do, so we have to assume that the water it calls forth is actually clean water: water that interacts with the world like real water does.  If I pour it on a small fire, I might put the fire out.  If I stir a sugar cube into it, the sugar will dissolve.  If I pour it onto a document, the ink will run.  And if I drink it - it will be as if I had drunk a cup of water.
This water also goes away after a minute:

...and the water evaporates in 1 minute.

Suppose I had poured the water onto a fire.  At the end of the minute, when the water disappears, does the fire relight?  Does the sugar cube reform?  Does the ink collect back into neat letters?  No.  Although not stated as a rule, the general motif for how magic works in 5e is that when you transmute something, the new thing made might have a limited duration, but any changes that thing makes in the world remain, even after the thing goes away.
What happens if it is no longer water at the end of the minute?
Although less frequently seen than the principle of 'persistent effects caused by temporary items', there is another principle in 5e magic.  If an item with a limited duration no longer exists at the time its duration expires - nothing happens.
This can be seen, for example, in the transmutation spell plant growth, where:

All plants in a half-mile radius centered on a point within range become enriched for 365 days. The plants yield twice the normal amount of food when harvested.

Suppose I harvest the plants at 355 days.  What happens eleven days later to the food I made?  Does half of it suddenly disappear?  No, because the effect of the enrichment goes away on only the plants.  At the moment I harvested them, they were no longer plants - they had become food.  As a rules set, D&D operates with categorical states of being, and things can instantaneously change from one state to another.  A piece of paper on the ground can be set aflame by a fireball.  The second I pick it up, it is impervious to the spell.  Its state has changed.
If the beckoned water is no longer water after a minute, it cannot evaporate.  If I true polymorphed a beckoned cup of water into a mouse, the mouse would not evaporate after a minute - but if I dropped my concentration on the mouse just before the minute was up, it would resume being water, and then evaporate.  If I froze the water into ice, the ice would not evaporate after a minute, because it would be ice, not water.  If I drank the water, and it had become incorporated into my body, it would no longer be water, it would be me.  And me doesn't evaporate.
Only the beckoned water that remains as water evaporates at the end of the duration.  Spells do what they say they do, but some of what they say they do is implicit.  The beckon water effect can be read as:

Alternatively, you create 1 cup of clean water either in an open container or on a surface[.  Any water that still remains after 1 minute evaporates].

How long does it take water to become part of my body?
If I drink the cup of water, how long does it take to go from being water, to being me?  Will it have become me by the end of its duration, or would it take longer than a minute?
D&D is not a simulator of biochemical metabolism.  In all other instances, such metabolic effects are also assumed to be instantaneous changes of state.  When I drink a potion of poison, or get stung by a giant scorpion, poison damage and/or the poisoned condition take effect immediately.  If I wait until five minutes before midnight to drink my daily supply of water, I do not gain a level of exhaustion at midnight 'because the water hasn't been absorbed yet'.  In the create food and water spell, we are told that:

The food spoils after 24 hours if uneaten.

We are not instructed that we have to wait until the food has been digested.  The trigger for the instantaneous change of state is being eaten; once eaten, it is no longer created food, it is us.
Conclusion
I have a beckoned cup of water.  If the water remains undrunk, it evaporates in a minute.  If I drink it, it is no longer water - it is me, and it has immediately slaked one cup's worth of my thirst for the day.  Once drunk, it cannot evaporate, because the water that was the product of the spell no longer exists.

Thank you for the thoughtful answer. I think this is a good way for the DM to argue why it would work to sustain, if they choose to go this way, and the kind of answer I was hoping for. As discussed on the 2014-5e question you kindly linked in a comments above, it would normally take 10 minutes or more for the body to assimilate drunk water, but the game is not a biology simulation, so for convenience ruling that once drunk the water is not going to be lost any more is much simpler and practical.

@NobodytheHobgoblin Simpler, more practical - and consistent with the way metabolism is abstracted in many other areas of the game.  If a DM is disallowing this, I think it is more honest to say "I don't like the consequences of this particular spell" rather than "That's unrealistic, it isn't how metabolism works (even though it works that way for other spells and effects I am fine with allowing)"

Ask your DM.
You have acknowledged in your question that D&D is not a physics simulator, yet you have chosen to ask this question anyway, treating D&D as a physics simulator. Since, as you have observed, D&D is not a physics simulator, only the DM knows what happens when you try to treat the game like a physics simulator.
You’ve already made what is probably the most pertinent observation for making a ruling here: allowing this cantrip to sustain you supplants the function of a higher level spell. Since spell levels tell us something about their relative power level (most of the time), we should be hesitant to allow cantrips to function similarly to 3rd level spells.
As for what happens when you drink, I would tend toward ruling that it causes harmless, but aggressive, belching since it evaporates in your stomach, without providing meaningful hydration. But that’s just the simulationist in me, your DM may rule otherwise.

Since there is very little info given, I guess the resulting answer would end up the same — ask your DM — but I don't think it is necessary for this answer to discard this question entirely as a physics simulation question.
The problem of what happens after drinking it, specifically whether it works as a source of drinking water is a very real and practical one and has nothing to do with physics, even if the questions puts emphasis on the evaporation.

@J.E The answer "Ask you DM" still fits. There's no guidance in the book as to what "evaporates" means for water that was drunk

IMHO, a good Ask your DM answer should provide some guidance to the possible options for the DM and their pros and cons. You can always ask your DM how something works in their game, so just stating that is not providing much value besides stating the obvious.

@NobodytheHobgoblin There’s a difference between saying “ask your DM” to a question that has a meaningful answer and saying “ask your DM” to question whose only answer is “ask your DM”. This is the latter.

No.
As you pointed out, a cantrip shouldn't replace a 3rd level spell.
When applying natural language to the text of a spell, you should not stick to the most convenient definition, and try to see what meaning the word has in a broader sense. Yes, evaporate could mean it turns into vapor, but...

Evaporate, verb.
[...] to disappear; vanish; fade: "His hopes evaporated."

Therefore, the water should disappear, without leaving residue.

Now, the fun part.
Even if you think the water should became vapor... let's go full-metal Physicist. I will round some numbers to the detriment of my demonstration.
A cup of water has ~240 ml. Water is ~18 grams per mol and has a density of 1000kg/m3. A cup of water has around 13 moles of water, rounding down.
13 moles of water, when turned into vapor (gas), occupies 22.4L of volume, at STP. Inside a human body, it should be more than this, but we already committed to approximations.
Therefore, the cup of water you just drank from your cantrip should expand, after 1 minute of the cast, to whooping 291 liters of volume. A human has around 60 liters of volume, meaning your skin now has to hold onto 350 liters of volume.
A sphere with 350 liters of volume has around 2.4sq.m of area. A human's skin is around 1.8sq.m of area. For the sake of fun, let's assume no holes let vapor escape and that the skin can stretch that far. Skin is quite stretchy, right?
Yes, I'm doing what every Physicist does and approximating a human to a sphere. We do it with cows, for crying out loud. It even has a bloody wikipedia page.
Congratulations. A new spell combo has been found, how to balloonify enemies. But as a Physisicst DM, I would rule it only works in a vacuum.
Fun part ended.

Or we could just assume the water created by a cantrip just vanishes without a trace. Therefore, drinkable but not nourishing.
Compare it to another cantrip. Prestidigitation can be used to create some water too. It also wouldn't nourish.

I can't believe for one second that someone wrote evaporate with respect to water and didn't mean turn into vapour. They probably didn't intend the consequences you noted, but that's a different matter, and probably shows that it actually doesn't evaporate when consumed more than anything.

Or you die. ;) If the water evaporates within the blink of an eye, it is likely to happen only if the water is super-heated in an instant - in your stomach or as it goes down your gullet.

Funny, before posting the question, I had done all kinds of gas expansion calculations myself, and concluded that if this was heat-based expansion, or even just expansion, and if it would expand no matter what, then getting someone to drink the water is a rather gruesome way to assassinate them.  I do think your dictionary reading of "evaporate" is a great way for the DM to resolve this as saying nothing happens with support other than power-level considerations.

@NobodytheHobgoblin Evaporating 240ml of water at room temperature requires enough heat to chill the person's body by ~2.5C

Yes, you can sustain with it.
While that is still an interpretation and ask your DM always safe, the word "clean" specifically added means the water is safe:

to clean (wounds or things or self) -> nothing in the rules refers to cleaning
to cook -> 1 min is to little
to drink -> not drinking can cause exhaustion

The only case where it was usefull in the cantrip to add "clean" is with regards to drinking, and if you couldn't really sustain from it that would have to be added as well

Hi there, welcome to the stack! When you have a minute, go ahead and take the [tour] and check out the [help] for more information. It's pretty rude of people to downvote your answer without any explanation, IMO. It could help if you had any sources that back up your claims, instead of stating that it's simply an interpretation (which gets dangerously close to an opinion answer, which this site doesn't recommend). Have fun and happy gaming!
